# Does this LINQ/EF Query in the Foreach command get executed multiple times?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I am using MVC3, .NET4.5, EF6.1, SQL Server 2008 SP2.

I have a line like below, in my view, which builds a table:

```
foreach (var item in Model.myOrder.OrderBy(r =>r.Supplier.CompanyType.SortOrder).ThenBy(r => r.SortOrder).ThenBy(r => r.Date).ThenBy(r => r.Id).ToList())
{
 <tr>
    <td>@item.Id</td>
    <td>@item.Supplier.Name</td>
    <td>@item.Date</td>
 </tr>
 }
```

Obviously I want the LINQ query to just query the DB once, and then the Foreach command to iterate around the inmemory collection. From my tracing, it seems that this foreach step seems to be taking longer than expected, around 250ms per iteration.

Am I correct in thinking that the query could be hitting the DB every iteration? If so then can I force a one time hit on the DB. I thought my use of .tolist() in the Foreach statement forced an eager load.

Thanks.

EDIT

I am not sure if my suspicions are correct as I have just altered my code to this:

```
    var myItems = Model.myOrder.OrderBy(r =>r.Supplier.CompanyType.SortOrder).ThenBy(r => r.SortOrder).ThenBy(r => r.Date).ThenBy(r => r.Id).ToList();
    foreach (var item in myItems )
{
 <tr>
    <td>@item.Id</td>
    <td>@item.Supplier.Name</td>
    <td>@item.Date</td>
 </tr>
 }
```

Comment: One thing I would check is if any of the properties are lazily loaded. The actual query might be an O(1) style query, but it could end up with an O(N+1) query if things are lazily loaded.

Comment: Thank you for this @Zipper. Can you or others confirm that a LINQ query in a foreach statement gets executed once only against the DB, excepting any N+1 issues that might exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior in EF6+ is to read query results into memory upon execution. So, in principle, your original code and your second pass should have nearly identical performance profiles.

See [this CodePlex article](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20December%206%2C%202012).

Edit: Incidentally, if you want to prove this to yourself, run a SQL profile session during the page render; you should see only a single execution of the query.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am pretty sure now that you are correct. Since "Glimpsing" further, I identified some redundant queries and some N+1 behaviour. Is ToList() not required any longer, as I added this to ensure an eager load.